# Symfony 3 - Define form as a service

Tags: php, forms, service, symfony

in my Symfony 3-master project, I use this code to create a form in a controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ApplicantType::class, $applicant);
```

Now I decided to make a service out of this form, so I can use EntityManager inside of it. So in Symfony2.x, this would be pretty easy, just with a declaration in services.yml and this line of code:

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get("applicant.form"), $applicant);
```

However, this is no longer possible in Symfony 3, because this first parameter expect a string, not the form itself.

So my question is: How do I create a form as a service in Symfony 3, or is there any other way how to pass EntityManager inside of the form?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Tag your service as a form and then pass the alias. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service.  Should work the same as S2.

Comment: Have you tried this:  `$form = $this->createForm("applicant.form", $applicant);`?

Answer (score 23):

Defining a form type as service does not imply passing the instance retrieved from to container to `createForm`. when doing this, the container is not involved as far as the form component is involved.

To use a form type registered as a service (with the `form.type` tag so that the form component knows about it), you just just reference it by its name (i.e. the fully qualified class name in Symfony 2.8+ and the type name in older versions) in `createForm` or in `FormBuilder::add`.
This is exactly what you do for Symfony core types btw (`text`, `choice` and so on), which are registered as services.
the code of your controller does not change at all when using the form type as a service rather than having a form type without dependency and registered implicitly on first usage.

Comment: Regarding the preferred way to pass dependencies requested by @Xatoo in the bounty, this depends of the kind of dependencies. If it is expected to change on each usage of the form type (for instance the QueryBuilder in the "entity" type of Symfony), it belongs to options. If it is the same all the time (the "doctrine" service to access the entity manager), it belongs to the constructor, to avoid forms using it to depend on the service too when passing options

Comment: Great, it did the trick for me too, i was trying to pass form service to `createForm` which did not work, and `SearchForm:class` worked fine and entity manager is also being passed by form service, that's magic.. :)

Comment: Hi dear stof. would you please update your answer, including a Symfony 3.3 example (type hinting service class, inside controller) ?

Comment: For Symfony 3.3+, there is no difference at all, except that the autoconfiguration feature may be adding the `form.type` tag automatically for you instead of adding it explicitly. You never get the form type instance yourselves in the controller.

Comment: @ChristopheCoevoet is it a good practice to use forms as services ?

Comment: Defining form *types* as a service is definitely a good practice (if you start a project with the Symfony Flex structure, which is the default since Symfony 4, all your form types are registered as services automatically). Form instances (created with the `createForm` method should not be services as they are stateful objects which are not reusable.

Answer (score 6):

This is what i did to inject a form as a service in Symfony 3 from my Symfony 2 Code.

**In my service.yml i changed**

```
issue.form:
    class: Gutersohn\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\IssueType
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: issue }
```

to

```
issue.form:
    class: Gutersohn\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\IssueType
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

**In my controller i changed**

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($this->container->get('issue.form'), $issue, [
        "method" => "post",
        "action" => $this->container->get('router')->generate("ticket_add")
]);
```

to

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(IssueType::class, $issue, [
        "method" => "post",
        "action" => $this->container->get('router')->generate("ticket_add")
]);
```

Comment: Beware that you won t have error if there is à typo in the class path in services.xml. I spent 3 days figuring it out

Answer (score 5):

In [issue #17013 on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17013), **aliemre** stated:

> Adding form.type tag is enough in your service definition.
>
> ```
> app.form.corporation_type:
>     class: App\CorporationBundle\Form\CorporationType
>     arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
>     tags:
>         - { name: form.type }
> ```
>
> Controller should remain same:
>
> ```
> $form = $this->createForm(CorporationType::class, $corporation);
> ```

I've tested and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to look into the problem and I dig into the change in github, which is this one:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/abca2d6fdc89479586e052cd11241d5a9bc885e5#diff-5c1348d69be32426ff20446c9e812365R64

Then I found the PR into Symfony which has this BC removal, I decided to ask why the reason and you can see it here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16075#issuecomment-165106123

I hope this helps you with the concept around it!

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out and pointing to this question on Github.

Comment: I was also curious about it! and I'm here to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

On symfony 3.4, you can easily create a service to, for example, inject EntityManager in your form :

class addDiverseType extends AbstractType
{

```
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

Then, you have to "transform" your form as service in the service.yml file :

```
 form.add_diverse:
    class: PlatformBundle\Form\addDiverseType
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Finally, you call your form in the controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(addDiverseType::class, $parameter);
```